# pygame Loading Images

Tags: python, pygame

I'm having some issues loading an image into pygame. I've searched through here and google and tried using `os.path.join` and just the full path. Nothing is working. The error I'm getting is: `libpng error: bad adaptive filter value`. Here is my code for trying to load in the image.

```
background = pygame.image.load("background/level1.png")
background_rect = background.get_rect()
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? I've also tried the following:

```
background = pygame.image.load(os.path.join("background","level1.png"))
background_rect = background.get_rect()
background = pygame.image.load("L:\\Spring 2014\\CSC177\\The End\\The End\\background\\level1.png")
background_rect = background.get_rect()
```

Comment: What does `pygame.image.get_extended()` return?

Comment: Try with another png file. The error suggests that there is something wrong with the file, not that you are passing it the file location incorrectly.

Comment: It is now working with jpg files. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so What I'm getting from this is you don't have the full `PIL` installed completely so try converting the image to a .gif which I believe is your problem. It is getting to the .png file, but it can't load it because you don't have the full PIL support in your python. So like I said I would convert the png to a gif file and try it again.

Comment: It works with loading in a jpg file. So I'll just convert all my images to jpg.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that the path is the issue here.. 
As long as the os command

```
os.path.exists(path)
```

evaluates to True when you supply the image's path, pygame should be able to find it. If I were you I would try to open an image with another format or in the worst case scenario reinstall pygame

Hope tha helped! 
Cheers,
Alex

Comment: Tried loading in a jpg image. It loads in just fine. I'm going to guess that the png files are messed up or something.

Comment: I'm glad to know that :) I'm using pngs all the time with pygame though and I never encountered a similar issue.. It might just be this particular image that generated the error..